# How can I prevent a function from loading in the admin screens?

Tags: wp-admin, actions

When I add this code to my theme's `functions.php` file, it crashes my admin panel. How can I prevent it from loading in the admin screens?

```
//add_action('init', 'hekim_sticky_header'); 
// I want load this only if it is not admin panel
```

Comment: Need a lot more details, what is it doing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`is_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) function to check:

```php
add_action( 'init', 'hekim_sticky_header' );
function hekim_sticky_header() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }
    // Rest of your function goes here.
}
```